# Updating gcc4.2.1 to gcc6.2.0 on mac

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

I have already installed gcc 6.2.0 with homebrew and it is located in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc6
```

I also have edited my path, so when i write

```
which gcc
```

the answer is

```
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc6/6.2.0/bin/gcc
```

Still when i want to find out which version is currently used the answer is:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I dont know what else to do. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is generating that last block of output? It's probably not `gcc`, or at least not the one you installed.

Comment: my input was 
     gcc --version